# heroku can't connect to my mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm deploying a nodejs app on heroku but an issue happend when I try to log in my app with my mongodb users collection

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

I had the 0.0.0.0/0 ip in my mongodb whitelist and it works well when I run my app localy

Here is my code to connect the database

```js
const mongoUrl = process.env.DB_URL;

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, {
    keepAlive: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb');
});
```

I have had the env var DB_URL in my heroku settings but it's still not working

I don't know what to do

Please help me

Comment: Where is your database hosted?

Comment: @Chris it is stored in a mongodb cloud cluster

Comment: And how is `DB_URL` being set?

Comment: @Chris it is set in Heroku settings, in Config Vars section (value : mongodb+srv://****:****@appname.yupjq.mongodb.net/appname?retryWrites=true&w=majority)